# Find the Highest number in O(logn) Complexity

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, binary-search

```
def peak(arr,n):
l = 0
r = n-1
while(l<=r):
    m = l + (r-l)//2
    
    if m>0 and m<n-1:    
        if arr[m+1]<arr[m] and arr[m]>arr[m-1]:
            return arr[m]
        elif arr[m+1]>arr[m] and arr[m]>arr[m-1]:
            l = m+1
        elif arr[m+1]<arr[m] and arr[m]<arr[m-1]:
            r = m-1
    elif m>0 and m>=n-1:
        if arr[m]>arr[m-1]:
            return arr[m]
    elif m<=0 and m<n-1:
        if arr[m+1]<arr[m]:
            return arr[m]
```

Question is -
Given an array in such a way that the elements stored in array are in increasing order initially and then after reaching to a peak element , elements stored are in decreasing order. Find the highest element.

Example:
Input:

11

1 2 3 4 5 6 5 4 3 2 1

5

1 2 3 4 5

Output:
6
5

Can anyone tell me what is wrong in my code?

Comment: Above example is running but on submitting I am getting 'Your program took more time than expected.Time Limit Exceeded
Expected Time Limit < 2.2sec
Hint : Please optimize your code and submit again.'

Comment: cleaner code means less cognitive load and more focus on the problem itself rather than  trying to understand the code running it.

Comment: You need to use ternary search if there is a strict time limit which will make it log3(N). The data can actually be modelled as a unimodal function. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_search

Comment: If duplicate elements are allowed, the loop doesn't end in some cases. Also if there is only one element in the array the loop doesn't end as well.

Comment: @SomeDude Duplicates are not allowed. I added the base case if n == 1 still i am getting the error .You can check it out https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/find-the-highest-number/0

Comment: @PratyushNarain I read the problem description.  It says "increasing" and "decreasing", not "strictly increasing" or "strictly decreasing".  I therefore would expect that duplicates are fair game.  Handle duplicates and try again.

Comment: @blhsing The problem says up to 100 test cases with up to 200 elements per array.  Python runs fast enough to handle that in 2.2 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the conditions in your code do not account for the case where there is only one element in the array, i.e, when `n` is `1`. When this happens none of the conditions would be true, and the `while` loop becomes an infinite loop.

You can solve the issue by simply returning `arr[m]` by default:

```
while(l<=r):
   m = l + (r-l)//2
   if m>0 and m<n-1:
       ... # your existing code
   else:
       return arr[m]
```